# How to deal with class that has too many parameters in constructor - Scala?

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, constructor, builder

I am modeling some data types which are intrinsically having lots of fields.

Then I am having the **ugly code**, where the class's constructor is having a long list of arguments, as well as all its subclasses.

I kind of doubt whether *BuilderPattern* is a good solution for this.

For example, this is the generic class `Transaction`:

```
class Transaction(
    source: String,
    format: String,
    id: String,
    amount: Double,
    currency: String,
    senderAccount: String,
    senderName: String,
    receiverAccount: String,
    receiverName: String,
    execDate: LocalSate,
    createdDateTime: Instant)
```

This is the subclass A `TxTypeA`, which has some special fields specific for typeA:

```
class TxTypeA(
    source: String,
    format: String,
    id: String,
    amount: Double,
    currency: String,
    senderAccount: String,
    senderName: String,
    receiverAccount: String,
    receiverName: String,
    execDate: LocalSate,
    createdDateTime: Instant,
    typeAField1: String,
    typeAField2: String,
    typeAField3: String
) extends Transaction(
    source,
    format,
    id,
    amount,
    currency,
    senderAccount,
    senderName,
    receiverAccount,
    receiverName,
    execDate,
    createdDateTime)
```

This is the subclass B `TxTypeB`, which has some special fields specific for typeB:

```
class TxTypeB(
    source: String,
    format: String,
    id: String,
    amount: Double,
    currency: String,
    senderAccount: String,
    senderName: String,
    receiverAccount: String,
    receiverName: String,
    execDate: LocalSate,
    createdDateTime: Instant,
    typeBField1: String,
    typeBField2: String,
    typeBField3: String,
    typeBField4: String,
    typeBField5: String,
    typeBField6: String,
    typeBField7: String
) extends Transaction(
    source,
    format,
    id,
    amount,
    currency,
    senderAccount,
    senderName,
    receiverAccount,
    receiverName,
    execDate,
    createdDateTime)
```

Anyone has some better solution for this?

**UPDATE:**

In my project, I created another class called `Party`, which wrapped the `Account` and `Name`, but this is just releasing the pain, not solving the problem in the core.

```
case class Party(account: String, name: String)

class Transaction(
    source: String,
    format: String,
    id: String,
    amount: Double,
    currency: String,
    senderParty: Party,
    receiverParty: Party,
    execDate: LocalSate,
    createdDateTime: Instant)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if inheritance is the best way to go here. maybe composition is better? Also is there a specific reason for these to not be case classes? and there are an awful lot of `String` maybe tagged types / refined types would make this more understandable as well? These are all not solutions per se but just a couple thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tidy this up a bit by making Transaction a trait:

```
trait Transaction {
  val source: String
  val format: String
  val id: String
  val amount: Double
  val currency: String
  val senderAccount: String
  val senderName: String
  val receiverAccount: String
  val receiverName: String
  val execDate: LocalState
  val createdDateTime: Instant
}

case class TxTypeA(
  source: String,
  format: String,
  id: String,
  amount: Double,
  currency: String,
  senderAccount: String,
  senderName: String,
  receiverAccount: String,
  receiverName: String,
  execDate: LocalState,
  createdDateTime: Instant,
  typeAField1: String,
  typeAField2: String,
  typeAField3: String
) extends Transaction

case class TxTypeB(
  source: String,
  format: String,
  id: String,
  amount: Double,
  currency: String,
  senderAccount: String,
  senderName: String,
  receiverAccount: String,
  receiverName: String,
  execDate: LocalState,
  createdDateTime: Instant,
  typeBField1: String,
  typeBField2: String,
  typeBField3: String,
  typeBField4: String,
  typeBField5: String,
  typeBField6: String,
  typeBField7: String
) extends Transaction
```

If you want, you can even combine these values into smaller case classes containing related fields, something like this:

```
case class Party(account: String, name: String)

trait Transaction {
  val source: String
  val format: String
  val id: String
  val amount: Double
  val currency: String
  val sender: Party
  val receiver: Party
  val execDate: LocalState
  val createdDateTime: Instant
}

case class TxTypeA(
  source: String,
  format: String,
  id: String,
  amount: Double,
  currency: String,
  sender: Party,
  receiver: Party,
  execDate: LocalState,
  createdDateTime: Instant,
  typeAField1: String,
  typeAField2: String,
  typeAField3: String
) extends Transaction

case class TxTypeB(
  source: String,
  format: String,
  id: String,
  amount: Double,
  currency: String,
  sender: Party,
  receiver: Party,
  execDate: LocalState,
  createdDateTime: Instant,
  typeBField1: String,
  typeBField2: String,
  typeBField3: String,
  typeBField4: String,
  typeBField5: String,
  typeBField6: String,
  typeBField7: String
) extends Transaction
```

Or you can go further, passing Transaction as a parameter rather than extending it:

```
case class Party(account: String, name: String)

case class Transaction (
  val source: String,
  val format: String,
  val id: String,
  val amount: Double,
  val currency: String,
  val sender: Party,
  val receiver: Party,
  val execDate: LocalState,
  val createdDateTime: Instant
)

case class TxTypeA(
  transaction: Transaction,
  typeAField1: String,
  typeAField2: String,
  typeAField3: String
)

case class TxTypeB(
  transaction: Transaction,
  typeBField1: String,
  typeBField2: String,
  typeBField3: String,
  typeBField4: String,
  typeBField5: String,
  typeBField6: String,
  typeBField7: String
)
```

It depends on your use-case and what is feasible. If you're doing something like formatting Json, I'd recommend extending it so the Json fields match up (or creating specific Reads etc).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use case classes to model related information? e.g. the sender and reciever in the transaction can be modelled as seperate case classes;

```
case class Account(id: String, name: String)


class Transaction(
    source: String,
    format: String,
    id: String,
    amount: Double,
    currency: String,
    sender: Account
    reciever: Account
    execDate: LocalSate,
    createdDateTime: Instant)
```

That way you reduce the amount of parameters in the constructor. You could then add helper methods to the Transaction class or implement a builder pattern, e.g. TransactionBuilder.withSender(senderName, senderAccountId)

Comment: yes, I am actually doing this in my project. but the original problem remains, I still have too many arguments.

Comment: Yes, but that is a business related choice. If all that information is required in the transaction, I guess there is no way around the number of fields in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I am looking to compose the fields in to other classes.

For example Transaction can be a composition of Sender, Receiver, Amount and so on.